# Android WebView App :: Errors Name : File error accessing recents directory ; Task 255 failed or timed out ; CancellationException

Tags: android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, broadcastreceiver, android-webview, android-handlerthread

I have ***lots of links*** in my app, I have used the Firebase database for ***data fetch*** and ***data send*** and also used ***broadcast receiver***.

**Most of the time my app is not crashing with these errors**, but sometimes it crashed. When it crashed, I opened the logcat the I found this

```
2022-04-22 02:22:46.387 1260-1445/? E/WifiVendorHal: getWifiLinkLayerStats_1_3_Internal(l.974) failed {.code = ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED, .description = }



2022-04-22 02:32:18.834 18124-18124/? E/A: Task 255 failed or timed out. Client 79711845498329053 disconnecting from SearchService!
    java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Task was cancelled.
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.s(PG:3)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.get(PG:4)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.eb.a(PG:1)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ci.r(PG:2)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.cb.run(PG:4)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.ba.run(PG:1)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8653)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
2022-04-22 02:32:18.838 18124-18124/? E/A: Task 255 failed or timed out. Client 79711845498329051 disconnecting from SearchService!
    java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Task was cancelled.
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.s(PG:3)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.get(PG:4)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.eb.a(PG:1)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ci.r(PG:2)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.cb.run(PG:4)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.ba.run(PG:1)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8653)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
2022-04-22 02:32:18.850 18124-17677/? E/BgTaskExecutorImpl: PERIODIC background task MDD_CELLULAR_CHARGING_TASK was cancelled.
    java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Task was cancelled.
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.s(PG:3)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.get(PG:4)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.eb.a(PG:1)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ci.r(PG:2)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.cb.run(PG:4)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.cf.b(PG:1)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.ci.run(PG:1)
        at com.google.android.libraries.i.ae.run(PG:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at com.google.android.libraries.i.i.run(PG:2)
        at com.google.android.libraries.i.p.run(PG:4)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
2022-04-22 02:32:18.857 18124-17615/? E/BgTaskExecutorImpl: PERIODIC background task MDD_WIFI_CHARGING_TASK was cancelled.
    java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Task was cancelled.
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.s(PG:3)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.get(PG:4)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.eb.a(PG:1)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ci.r(PG:2)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.cb.run(PG:4)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.cf.b(PG:1)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.ci.run(PG:1)
        at com.google.android.libraries.i.ae.run(PG:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at com.google.android.libraries.i.i.run(PG:2)
        at com.google.android.libraries.i.p.run(PG:4)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

sometimes it shows this also

```
    2022-04-22 09:28:15.894 1928-2047/? E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).

2022-04-22 09:49:15.232 21150-21150/ W/System.err:     at w.Internet_Checker_BroadCast_Reciver.onReceive(Internet_Checker_BroadCast_Reciver.java:27)
```

I have studied it more. I found a thing , when the app is crashing the logcat prints as the last line is(will it be the reason?) :

```
2022-04-22 12:22:25.941 17481-17552/w D/OneSignal: UserStateSynchronizer internalSyncUserState from session call: false jsonBody: null
```